# How to export a rendered bar chart with axios.get() array data to a higher level component in vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-chartjs

I am displaying a series of chart vue components on a parent vue page. While testing axios calls with one of the charts, I am able to return a list to populate the bardata. I am tracking this.bardata all the way up to the mounted() method, and when I call this.renderChart(this.bardata,this.options), bardata seems to disappear.

current barchart component:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  //Importing Bar class from the vue-chartjs wrapper
  import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
  const API_URL = 'http://localhost:58881'
  //Exporting this so it can be used in other components
  export default {
    extends: Bar,
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveData],
    data () {
      return {
        bardata: {
              labels: ['Failed', 'Successful', 'Total'],
              datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Attempts',
                backgroundColor: '#455A64',
                //Data to be represented on y-axis
                data: null,
                borderWidth: 1
              }
              ]
            },
        //Chart.js options that controls the appearance of the chart
        options: {
          title : {
            display : true,
            position : "top",
            text : "",
            fontSize : 18,
            fontColor : "#111"
          },
          legend: {
            display: true
          },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales : {
            yAxes : [{
            ticks : {
              min : 0
            }
            }]
          }
        }
      };
    },
    mounted () {
      //renderChart function renders the chart with the datacollection and options object.
      console.log(this.bardata)
      this.renderChart(this.bardata, this.options)
    },
    created() {
        axios.get(API_URL + "/api/admin/GetChart" ,{
          params:{
          chartName: 'LoginsBarChart',
          userToken: this.userToken,
        } ,
        headers: {
          token: this.userToken
        }
        }).then(response => {
            this.bardata.datasets.data = response.data
        })          
      }
  }
</script>
```

Within my browser's console, this.bardata shows the appropriate array [0,2,2].

This is my parent vue which displays the chart component:

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <h1>Usage Analysis Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="Chart">
      <div class="column">
        <h3>Logins vs Failures</h3>
        <logins-bar-chart></logins-bar-chart>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  import LoginsBarChart from '@/components/LoginsBarChart.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'VueChartJS',
    components: {
      // Bar Chart 
        LoginsBarChart,
    }
  }
</script>
```

[Console and Frontend Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiSAL.png)
(first time post, need 10 reputation to post actual image)

Overall, I cannot see where I am going wrong, if the array is correct all the way up to and even inside the mounted() method, why does the chart not populate on the browser?

Before creating the axios call, In bardata.datasets.data, i would hardcode [0,2,2],

```
 bardata: {
              labels: ['Failed', 'Successful', 'Total'],
              datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Attempts',
                backgroundColor: '#455A64',
                //Data to be represented on y-axis
                data: null,
                borderWidth: 1
              }
              ]
            },
```

and the chart would show up fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing a request on the created method that ends with a promise. This promise wont always resolve before the mounted method is run. My suggestion would be to move the renderChart call to the .then on the created method

```
mounted () {
  //renderChart function renders the chart with the datacollection and options object.
  console.log(this.bardata)

},
created() {
    axios.get(API_URL + "/api/admin/GetChart" ,{
      params:{
      chartName: 'LoginsBarChart',
      userToken: this.userToken,
    } ,
    headers: {
      token: this.userToken
    }
    }).then(response => {
        this.bardata.datasets.data = response.data
        this.renderChart(this.bardata, this.options)
    })          
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work for my specific problem, but I see what you mean, and fixed that first. I will say this led me to the appropriate answer!!! Thanks Anteo!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! bardata was never being sent back to the original return parameter so I figured I would try to set the entire bardata with my created()
here is the working result:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  //Importing Bar class from the vue-chartjs wrapper
  import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
  const API_URL = 'http://localhost:58881'
  //Exporting this so it can be used in other components
  export default {
    extends: Bar,
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveData],
    data () {
      return {
        bardata: {},
        //Chart.js options that controls the appearance of the chart
        options: {
          title : {
            display : true,
            position : "top",
            text : "",
            fontSize : 18,
            fontColor : "#111"
          },
          legend: {
            display: true
          },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales : {
            yAxes : [{
            ticks : {
              min : 0
            }
            }]
          }
        }
      };
    },
    created() {
        axios.get(API_URL + "/api/admin/GetChart" ,{
          params:{
          chartName: 'LoginsBarChart',
        } ,
        headers: {
          token: this.userToken
        }
        }).then(response => {
          this.bardata = {
              labels: ['Failed', 'Successful', 'Total'],
              datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Attempts',
                backgroundColor: '#455A64',
                //Data to be represented on y-axis
                data: response.data,
                borderWidth: 1
              }
              ]
            },
            //console.log(this.bardata)
            this.renderChart(this.bardata, this.options)

        })          
      }
  }
</script>
```